# How to detect service type on remote host and port

Tags: networking

My browser started to wait 192.168.101.1:8888 as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832304/firefox-becomes-veeery-slow-and-strangily-waits-for-192-168-101-18888)

I'd like to check what the service listens on 192.168.101.1:8888

When I connect to it with telnet it echoes back characters I send.

How can I find out the service type?

Comment: This might become part of the troubleshooting process for the original issue, but you shouldn't make a new question with an XY problem.

Comment: You might want to look into `nmap`, a port scanning tool. Running `nmap -v -A 192.168.101.1` should give you a basic idea of what network services are running on that device, maybe even what OS it runs.